# Django FloatField and DecimalField creation return different than object in database

Tags: python, django, model

I've just realise that in Django2, the object at the creation (using xxx.objects.create or xxx.save) return an object that is a little bit different than the object which is really in database (MODEL.objects.get(*the object created*)). You can see it using DecimalField or FloatField:

```
class Product(Model):
     price = FloatField()
```

then running the shell (python manage.py shell):

```
from *project*.models import Product
a = Product.objects.create(price=30)
# or "a = Product(price=30); a.save()"
b = Product.objects.get(price=30)
a == b  # True
str(a.price) == str(b.price)  # False : "30" == "30.0"
```

Is this a bug from django ? Why django does not return the same object ?

Because when you create an object using the xxx.objects.create method, you expect it to return the same object (at least the same copy) than what you get when you search this object in the database.
I found the source code of the create method:

```
def create(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
    and returning the created object.
    """
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    self._for_write = True
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    return obj
```

Many thanks !

EDIT: my question is: why both objects are differents ? Why when I create the object, django does not return the object with a float but one with a int ?

EDIT: Thanks @Willem Van Onsem

> if you create an object, you assign the attributes the object you pass
>   to them (here 30). Whereas if you fetch data, the fields will read the
>   result of the database response, and interpret it (float30)

But I still think it is better if at creation, Django return the "interpret data". EDIT: I'm thinking I'm wrong: it would be too magic, and python does not like "magic".

Comment: A `float` with `30` is not the same as an `int` with `30`, but these are *equivalent*. If you convert these to strings, then this can generate different strings, so no, this is not a bug.

Comment: If I had use DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) instead of FloatField, django would still return (at creation) a object with a price <int> while the database would return a object with a price <Decimal>. Why ?

Comment: because if you create an object, you assign the attributes the object you pass to them (here `30`). Whereas if you fetch data, the fields will read the result of the database response, and *interpret* it. For a `FloatField` this thus results in a `float`, and for a `DecimalField` in a `Decimal`.

Comment: Just FYI, if something is "solved" it should be posted as an answer instead of an edit to the question. Also the community consensus is that "[Solved]" should not be added to the title of the question; see  [Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/171094).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a bug from django? Why django does not return the same object?

**No**. This is *not* a bug. If you `.create(..)` an object, you first construct a `Model` object, and then call `.save()`. But that thus means that the fields take the value you give them. `30` is by default an `int`, so that means that if you query for `type(a.price)`, you get:

```
>>> type(a.price)
<class 'int'>
```

If you query the database, for example with `Model.objects.get(price=30)`, you however construct a query, for example here the query will look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM project_price
WHERE price = 30
```

The database will respond by a sequence of records. These records are *interpreted* by the Django ORM, and the different fields will construct Python counterparts. For a [**`FloatField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#floatfield) will thus convert the "string" that contains the response of the database to a `float` through the [**`to_python`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L293).

Now in Python a `float` and `int` are two different types, but that does not mean that two such objects can not be equivalent, for example:

```
>>> float(30) == int(30)
True
```

But if we convert these to strings, then these both yield different strings:

```
>>> str(int(30))
'30'
>>> str(float(30))
'30.0'
```